# Why is there a PostgreSQL Turtle?

Tags: postgresql

I was just checking out the [propaganda page for PostgreSQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20170715224420/http://www.postgresql.org/community/propaganda/) and I found this little piece of art:

[image]

It is the **"Turtle Style"** PostgreSQL logo. How old is this, and did PostgreSQL ever officially use a turtle instead of an elephant? What is the story here?

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/658/1396) for the discussion about topicality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The turtle iconography has historic significance dating from the platform that preceded PostgreSQL.

As noted by Hermit Hacker on [this pgsql-hackers thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3502EBF6.B4484720@sid.trust.ee#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20%20predecessors%20used%20the%20Turtle%20logo) from 1998 discussing potential re-branding for postgres:

> PostgreSQL predecessors used the Turtle logo

The postgres predecessor in question is Ingres DB. <sup>[Ingres wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingres_(database)#Postgres),[Postgres wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#:%7E:text=It%20was%20originally%20named,Ingres%20database), [postgresql.org history (archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180201082046/https://www.postgresql.org/about/history/#:%7E:text=Stonebraker%20started,after%20Ingres)</sup>

> Postgres (**Post** In**gres**), a project which started in the mid-1980s, later evolved into PostgreSQL

And as noted on [this berkeley.edu resource](https://dsf.berkeley.edu/www/logos.html#:%7E:text=Turtles)

> The turtle was adopted as a mascot by the INGRES group in the '70s because "it's slow but it gets there.'' It was retained as the POSTGRES mascot for sentimental reasons.

[image: database-research-group-uc-berkeley-turtle-world-logo]

This wording matches nicely from another Hermit Hacker quote on [another related thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSF.3.96.980603235349.2950C-100000@thelab.hub.org#:%7E:text=I%20kinda%20like,dependable)

> ...I kinda like an elephant or turtle...a little slower, but highly dependable...

Answer (score 25):

As stated in the official [Identity Guidelines](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

> In Japan, a turtle logo is used in place of the elephant due to domestic terrorist symbolism.

The elephant has negative connotations in Japan because members of a cult which uses an elephant as its logo were responsible for some terrorist attacks.

The group in question wore blue elephant masks while campaigning for Japan's parliament a few years before their murder spree, rather than it being exactly a logo. Personally, I would rather not post links to pages about their exploits, but if you want to go looking it doesn't take two minutes on a google search to find articles if you use words like: elephant deadly sarin gas tokyo

You can see the turtle iconography used quite extensively on [the Japanese Language PostgreSQL site](https://www.postgresql.jp/npo/logo/?searchterm=logo)

While other Japanese companies like [Zojirushi](http://www.zojirushi-world.com/) may retain use of the Blue Elephant iconography, that company in particular dates back to 1918 and [its branding dates from the 60's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zojirushi_Corporation). PostgresSQL's use of elephant iconography dates from only the late 90's which corresponds very nearly with the horrible events previously mentioned and would have no doubt been a contributing factor in the community decision to not use the imagery in Japan.

Comment: Elephant logos are used by Japanese brands, for example [Zojirushi](http://www.zojirushi-world.com/)