# Why did PostgreSQL choose an elephant as it's logo?

Tags: postgresql

Why did PostgreSQL choose an elephant as it's logo? It wasn't clear from [logo wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logo).

**UPDATE:** Now wiki updated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the email thread [postgreSQL and history of relational databases](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.GSO.4.62.0503281829140.17555@ra.sai.msu.su), [Oleg Bartunov](http://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/speakers/29.en.html) states that the logo idea probably originated from a [PostgreSQL logo](http://www.pgsql.ru/db/mw/msg.html?mid=1238939) thread on the `pgsql-hackers` mailing list. Quote:

> [...]
>   but if you want an animal-based logo, how about some sort of elephant?
>   After all, as the Agatha Christie title read, elephants can remember ...
>
> David Yang

Answer (score 6):

Also consider [the related official "propaganda" page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170715224420/http://www.postgresql.org/community/propaganda/)

There you can see that a *turtle* is used for Japan, which has been discussed before on dba.SE:
[Why is there a PostgreSQL Turtle?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17691/why-is-there-a-postgresql-turtle)

.. and on pgsql-general mailing list:
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/92869e660906240901s74693458xec141a644289114c@mail.gmail.com

Here is the according Japanese web page:
http://www.postgresql.jp/npo/logo/?searchterm=logo

Answer (score -1):

Is it because an elephant never forgets

Comment: How does your answer improve on the existing accepted one?